# How to add attribute to a XML node created using Import node

Tags: c#

I'm cloning an XML node from one XML to another n number of times. To identify each node i want to add an index attribute to it.

Here is the code is I use to Import node.

```
 XmlDocument template = new XmlDocument();
 template.Load(filelocation);
 XmlDocument Neweventlist= new XmlDocument();
 XmlNamespaceManager namespaces = new      XmlNamespaceManager(template.NameTable);

namespaces.AddNamespace("n", "http://www.hp.com/2009/software/opr/data_model");

XmlNode node = template.SelectSingleNode(".//n:event", namespaces);

Neweventlist.Load(eventlist_location);

    Neweventlist.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Neweventlist.ImportNode(template.DocumentElement, true));
```

Please help how i can set attribute for the new node that i'm adding.

Template document:

```
  <event>
 <server></server>
 </event>
```

output doc:

```
<eventlist>
<event index="0">
<server></server>
</event>
<event index="1">
<server></server>
</event>
<event index="2">
<server></server>
</event>
</eventlist>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with sample input XML document and expected output XML document?

Comment: @codeninja I have updated with the sample doc

Comment: @codeninja I'm able to append and iterate event node number of times i want but while appending using above code i want to set unique index attribute to each event node

Comment: the solution provided by karthik is good enough to solve your problem; if you still face any problem, let me know.

Comment: @codeninja yes the issue is resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before adding the node to the Document,

```
XmlNode node = Neweventlist.ImportNode(template.DocumentElement, true); //Get the node
XmlAttribute attribute= Neweventlist.CreateAttribute("index"); // create attribute
attribute.Value = 0; //set the appropriate value
node.Attributes.Append(attribute); // add the attribute to node
```

Then add the node to the element,

```
Neweventlist.DocumentElement.AppendChild(node);
```